# TeamViewer offline/online status of the remote computer

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm a newbie with TeamViewer and my question is:
On both computers TeamViewer was setup.
On my computer in the TeamViewer I see the remote computer has status offline.

The remote computer has Windows 7 on it.

My question is: when I'm able to see the ONLINE status of the remote computer and able to connect to it - when it is just turned on, or any user has to login in into Windows system with a password before I'm able to connect to it?